# how do i write this method that returns the larger string?

Tags: java, string, methods, max

I am completely new to programming (java) and our teacher asks us to make some excercises in my programming lab.

Now I can't seem to find out how to write the correct method. 
This is the question:
Write a method  max that has two string  parameters  and returns the larger  of the two.

I have

```
String string1, string2;
public max Strings(string1.length(), string2.length())
{
    if (string1.length()>string2.length)
    {
    return string1;
    else if (string1.length()<string2.length)
        return string2;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to take some time to learn the basic syntax of Java. Read a Java introductory book or tutorial.

Comment: What is a larger string? You mean the longer one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String max(String a, String b) {
    return (a.length() > b.length()) ? a : b;
}
```

There is the condition that both strings are of equal length which is not tested for, also null and empty strings,

Comment: i see where and what i messed up ;) thank you (same goes for the comment below)

Comment: Stupid edit which has just made it hard for a learner to understand,

Answer (score 0):

- In Java, all functions - even static ones - must be in a class
- Java function definitions are return-type then name then parameters
- You must decide which string to return if they are the same length, or explicitly return NULL

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LongerString {

    public static String max(String a, String b) {
        String maxString = "";
        if (a.length() > b.length())
            maxString = a + " is longer";
        if (b.length() > a.length())
            maxString = b + " is longer";
        if (a.length() == b.length())
            maxString = "Both strings have the same length";
        return maxString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(max("hey", "hello")); // output: "hello is longer"
    }

}
```

As you can see, I've created a variable called "maxString" that will contain the string that is longer. "length()" get the character length of the string.
If both of the strings have the same length, then "maxString" will equal "Both strings have the same length". Then, the function returns "maxString".